# Opera: weird problem jQuery fade effect

Tags: jquery, opera, effects, fade

I have some a tags with a nice fade hover in Chrome, FF, IE and Safari it's working great but Opera does someting weird...

I have made a jsFiddle so you people can see what i mean: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamwire/d3VXU/)

All the first (green) buttons will work nice in Opera but when you go on one of the others then Opera don't show the hover effect?

Comment: Might have to do with the use of sprites for your buttons images. The first button use the sprite at 0,0 (no offset) as the background, and all other buttons use an offset, which could cause this issue on Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my awnser...

I had a overflow : hidden; on my a tags when i deleted that everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sprites you use for the button images with separates images without offset on them to see if it's gonna work in Opera. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not working. I have made a single image for the blue button but the problem stays.